# Use different thinstation network configuration files for diffrent OS booting through PXE

Tags: rdp, pxe-boot, thin-client, tftp

I want to use thinstation to boot to RDP client which connects to either Ubuntu or Windows server 2008 R2. The user should be able to choose which OS they want to connect to. I've added the following to labels in *default* file at pxelinux.cfg directory.

Label Thinstaion-Windows
Kernel windows/vmlinuz
Append initrd=windows/initrd

Label Thinstaion-Ubuntu
Kernel ubuntu/vmlinuz
Append initrd=ubuntu/initrd

My problem is that both this choices use a single thinstaion.conf.network located in tftp root directory, whereas I want to make the thinclients pull the thinstaion.conf.network from inside the OS specific directory. So both OS have there own thinstaion.conf.network file. ex-
windows/thinstaion.conf.network
and
ubuntu/thinstation.conf.network

I don't want to use thinsation.hosts file as it will restrict user to a single OS and they won't be able to choose the RDP server of there choice.